# How do I create a segment in Google Analytics of users that liked, tweeted, or pinned?

Tags: google-analytics

Stack Overflow!

**TL;DR version**

I'm sending Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest events to Google, using their new ["social" quasi-event-thingamajig](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1683971?hl=en).  I can see the *raw count* of social events in GA (great!) but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to measure the change in *rate* at which people are doing something social.  This is important, because our traffic is highly variable.

**More Detail**

I run some celebrity news websites that give people important information about what's happening with the Kardashians, etc.  We get a non-trivial amount of traffic that is highly variable from day to day.

I am using the latest Google Analytics (analytics.js), and I have recently made some changes to my sharing bar. Previously, I used the stock Facebook and Tweet buttons, but now I've moved to using my own links, and I'm subscribing those links in my javascript. For instance, here's my Facebook code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(targetUrl) {
  ga('send', 'social', 'facebook', 'unlike', targetUrl);
});
```

This all seems to be working - I can look in my Google Analytics and see a graph of social events.  Social events go up, they go down. People share, they tweet. Great!

But what I want to know is, are they sharing *more* or *less* than they used to when I make a change? What's the change in the ratio of people that did something social to people that didn't?

Did "shares" go up on Tuesday because the share button is was in the best possible place, or did it go up because we happened to have six times the number of users on Tuesday?

In order to figure that out, I think i'd like to create a segment of "users that did something social during their visit."  So I can say: "Did the *percentage* of users who did anything social go up, or did it go down?"

Can anyone offer any insight into how I can get this? I keep poking at the Google Analytics reporting tools to find something like "Create a segment: Session >> Contains >> Social action", but I'm not seeing anything like that.

All advice is appreciated!

UPDATE: so far, I hear that "Unfortunately, I don't believe social events can be used for segments or goal completions."  I have a hunch that this answer-er is right.  Can anyone snatch victory from the jaws of defeat here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe social events can be used for segments or goal completions. I would either replace or supplement existing social event tracking with standard GA event tracking, e.g.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(targetUrl) {
  ga('send', 'social', 'facebook', 'unlike', targetUrl);
});
```

becomes

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(targetUrl) {
  ga('send', 'social', 'facebook', 'unlike', targetUrl);
  ga('send', 'event', 'facebook', 'unlike', targetUrl);
});
```

Once you're tracking these social actions as standard events, a whole new world opens up. You can create a segment based on these events or (likely more helpfully) [set them up as goals](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en). Once goals are set up, you can see various metrics around goal completion (including goal conversion rate) in a number of reports, as well as in the Goals-specific reports.

Comment: sean-adams, I agree with you that if I start (well, to be more precise, if I go back to) using standard events, I can indeed set them up as goals: "User did something social", and I can test various things to see what causes users to complete that goal.

Answer (score 0):

As for the A/B testing that will check whether or not the location of the sharing buttons made the difference, you can make it in a little bit dirty way by changing the name of the "action" of the event. This way you can breakdown which location yielded more events, in comparison to the amount of sessions.

So you can do something like the following, serving it 50/50 on your page. Let's say you are testing whether it performs better on the left side of the page, or the right side:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'facebook', 'click (left side)', targetUrl);

ga('send', 'event', 'facebook', 'click (right side)', targetUrl);
```

And then to see in the reports how it performed on a specific page):

[image: Events]

*(Note: I made a small mistake in the screenshot. In your dashboard you will see it under "event action", not "event label", which you keep for the target URL)*

Note that I used "click" and not "unlike". Since you use the social network as the event category, it's better to use the event action similar so the comparison you make for the buttons location won't depend on the event category.

Then, if you managed to serve it 50/50, compare it to the traffic on a specific page, then you know how many events the location yielded. If you have 500 visits on that page, and 50 events on "right side", and 90 events on "left side", then you got your conclusion. You will be also be able to do it for a group of pages and see in general, which one performs better.

There are other ways to do it, such as using the experiments of GA, but from your post I realized that it won't be feasible. My recommendation is to check out 3rd party tools for a/b micro testing, they might help you to find out as well which location serves better (the downside is that you might not see it in GA).

Comment: Thank you, dm-guy!  If I understand what you're suggesting, I think you're saying that I would do this using _events_, and not the new social tracking.  I'm pretty sure I know how I would do this using vanilla events (much as you describe above) -- my question was if it is possible using social.  So far, it seems like the answer is "no, it's not possible."

Comment: Well, I did not do it like this before, but after reading again GA docs on social events I'm pretty sure it's possible. Check sean-adams comment about turning them into goals since you might need it. If you would like to use the social events for A/B testing, then you can edit the social action to "like-right", or "like-left". I suggested to do it as a generic event  (with the label "click") so you won't mess up social event with user interaction event, and you will be able to compare interactions, whether it is a "like" or "tweet" or "share". But either way will get you where you want.